# phpeclipse does not work when renaming a folder

Tags: eclipse, phpeclipse

I have a folder containing some files and sub-folders.  If I rename the folder using the eclipse 'refactor'->'rename' command you would expect the folder to be renamed but that is not what happens.

A new folder is created with the new name and containing all the **files** while the existing folder does not go away, instead it contains all the **sub-folders**.

This is weird and really annoying - is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this one finally.  There is a tickbox that says **rename subpackages** you need to have this selected or else you get the weird behaviour above.